# How to replace SQL with bash variable of SQL command output

Tags: sql, json, bash, variables, psql

I am working on a program in bash that checks for valid JSON files before loading them into a table. The process first runs f_check_valid_json to verify the JSON. This process runs f_exe_sql_stmnt() that returns a column of bad files, stored in variable bad_fl_list. I would like to be able to input bad_fl_list in the WHERE clause of my update and delete sections of the function.

Right now, the SQL fails when there is more than one JSON file ID in bad_fl_list

```
  f_exe_sql_stmnt(){
      db=$1
      sql_str=$2
      psql -d "$db" -Atc "$sql_str"
      if [ $? -gt 0 ]
      then
        echo "======================================================================="
        echo "***Error: Database error while executing sql statement($sql_str)..."
        exit 123
      fi
    }


    f_check_valid_json() {
      echo "*** checking for valid JSON format***"
      sql_stmnt="Select json_fl_id from json_stgng where is_valid_json(json_datarec_fl) = false;"
      bad_fl_list=$(f_exe_sql_stmnt "$t_db" "${sql_stmnt}")
      echo "BAD FILE LIST: ${bad_fl_list}"
      if [ ! -z "$bad_fl_list" ]
      then
          echo "BAD JSON LIST IS NOT EMPTY"
          echo "*** updating balancing table to reflect bad file ***"
          updt_bal_log_str="UPDATE ${bal_log_tbl} SET trgt_load_stus_cd ='F' where json_fl_id in ($bad_fl_list);"
          f_exe_sql_stmnt "$DB" "$updt_bal_log_str"
          echo "*** deleting bad JSON file record from staging with file ID: ${bad_fl_list}"
          delete_stmnt="delete from ${stg_tbl}  where json_fl_id in ($bad_fl_list);"
          f_exe_sql_stmnt "$t_db" "${delete_stmnt}"
      fi
    }
```

Here is some example output from the logs:

```
+ psql -d dedw -Atc 'UPDATE json_load_bal_dtl_log SET trgt_load_stus_cd ='\''F'\'' where json_fl_id in (O21181043417
O21181043417
O21181003641);'
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "O21181043417"
LINE 2: O21181043417
        ^
```

Comment: It looks like you have invalid sytax in the `where ` clause.  Specifically, the ids in the `where json_fl_id in (O21181043417....` are not comma-separated.

Comment: You might try changing the query `"Select json_fl_id from json_stgng where is_valid_json(json_datarec_fl) = false;"`    to something like: `"Select STRING_AGG(json_fl_id, ', ') from json_stgng where is_valid_json(json_datarec_fl) = false;"`

Comment: @j_b works with:
STRING_AGG('''' || json_fl_id || '''', ', ')

Thanks!